# Find repeated words

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have this assignment where need to

> Write a method that takes a String parameter. If the String has a double letter (i.e. contains the same letter twice in a row) then it should return true. Otherwise, it should return false.
>
> This method must be named hasRepeat() and have a String parameter. This method must return a boolean.

However, when I check in my code, I am failing some tests.

It says that it isn't returning `false` when there are no repeated letters.

Here is my code:

```java
public static boolean hasRepeat(String word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < word.length(); j++) {
            if (word.substring(i, i + 1).equals(word.substring(i, j))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[image: Failed test]

Comment: It's because j will always be initalized with `i+1`, so you check if the same substrings are equal to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need in nested loops. All we have to do is to check if *current* char equals to *previous*:

```
public static boolean hasRepeat(String word) 
{
   // hasRepeat is a public method; we shoud be ready for any input
   if (word == null)
       return false;

   // here we start from 1: there's no previous char for charAt(0)
   for (int i = 1; i < word.length(); ++i)
     if (word.charAt(i - 1) == word.charAt(i))
       return true;

   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when checking the string, the loop skips the last two string, we can fix this by adding the length of the string to 1. Here is the code.
[What's also different between our code is the substring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGZfX.png)

Comment: There are multiple issues with their approach, the main one being nesting loops. Also, please make sure to share code using the appropriate formatting rather than images

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).